# How to set Expect to a Extension method in Rhino Mocks 3.6

Tags: c#, testing, extension-methods, rhino, expectations

Good afternoon

I have a class and it has an associated extension method.

```
public class Person{
    public int ID {get;set}
    public string Name {get;set}
}
```

Extension method:

```
public static class Helper {
   public static int GetToken(this Person person){
       int id = 0;
       //Something here is done to read token from another service...
       return id;
   }
}
```

Now I am trying to use Rhino and test this method

```
public void readPersonToken(int personId) {

   var person = Person.GetPersonInfo(personId);//we consume a service here
   Console.Writeline(person.GetToken());//get token is consuming another service

}
```

Supposing I am writing my test and have already an interface that calls GetPersonInfo()

```
var _interface = MockRepository.GenerateMock<IMyInterface>();
```

and the main Expect is

```
_interface.Expect(x => x.GetPersonInfo(2))
          .Return(new Person { ID=2, Name = "A Stubbed Monica!" });
```

how can I create a test for the extension metod GetToken?

Comment: It's hard to follow exactly what's going on here, especially as the interesting part is the code you've removed from the extension method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Extension methods are just syntatic sugar for static methods.  So what you really need is the ability to mock the static method here.  Unfortunately this is not possible in Rhino Mocks.

See the following StackOverflow thread for more details

- [Mocking Static methods using Rhino.Mocks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/540239/mocking-static-methods-using-rhino-mocks)

To mock a static method you need a mocking framework which actually uses the CLR profiler to intercept method calls.  As the thread mentions TypeMock should be able to do this.

Answer (score 0):

It should be possible by creating Stub for the extension methods.

[Extension methods in Mono 2.4 and RhinoMocks 3.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1698434/extension-methods-in-mono-2-4-and-rhinomocks-3-5)