# AssertWasCalled when there is a "this" parameter

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nunit, caliburn.micro, rhino-mocks

I am trying to test that Caliburn.Micro method, `PublishOnUIThread()` is called:

```
public static class EventAggregatorExtensions
{
 ...        
      public static void PublishOnUIThread(this IEventAggregator eventAggregator, object message);
 ...
}
```

I am trying to test like this:

```
//assert
_eventAggregator.AssertWasCalled(x => 
x.PublishOnUIThread(Arg<object>
.Is.Anything));
```

but get the error:

> System.InvalidOperationException : When using `Arg<T>`, all arguments
>   must be defined using `Arg<T>.Is, Arg<T>.Text, Arg<T>.List, Arg<T>.Ref
>   or Arg<T>.Out`. 2 arguments expected, 1 have been defined.

However, I cannot force the method to take 2 parameters. I'm new to testing so I'm not sure how to work around this.

Comment: Not possible to mock extension methods in Rhino, http://stackoverflow.com/a/5488700/368552 You could wrap them in an interface however and mock the interface

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to framework documentation, [The Event Aggregator](http://caliburnmicro.com/documentation/event-aggregator) is defined as followed.

```
public interface IEventAggregator {
    bool HandlerExistsFor(Type messageType);
    void Subscribe(object subscriber);
    void Unsubscribe(object subscriber);
    void Publish(object message, Action<Action> marshal);
}
```

As you already know, `PublishOnUIThread` is an [Event Aggregator Extension](https://github.com/Caliburn-Micro/Caliburn.Micro/blob/master/src/Caliburn.Micro/EventAggregatorExtensions.cs) method applied to the interface which calls the `void Publish(object message, Action<Action> marshal);` method.

In this case you can assert that method (`IEventAggregator.Publish`) when trying to test publishing an event as you cannot mock the extension methods.

```
//assert
_eventAggregator.AssertWasCalled(x => 
x.Publish(Arg<object>.Is.Anything, Arg<Action<Action>>.Is.Anything));
```